# How to have Python Infinite while / else statement with break?

Tags: python

The while loop in my code refuses to reach else statement when I use the while infinite loop with a break statement in it, and I'm really confused why this is happening:

```
        test_list = [1, 2, 3, 5]
        idx = 0

        while True:
            if test_list[idx] == 3:
                print("found it")
                break
            idx += 1

        else:
            print("not found it")
```

When I try the same code with regular while(non-infinite while), everything is fine and we can have a while statement with a break in it and have an else statement as well.

```
        test_list = [1, 2, 3, 5]
        idx = 0
        found = False


        while idx < len(test_list):
             if test_list[idx] == 3:
                found = True
                print("found it")
                break
             idx += 1

        else:
            print("not found it")
```

Comment: The else block is only run if the while loop exits because the condition is no longer true

Comment: The `else` of a loop is executed *when the loop naturally ends __without `break`__*. The only way to exit a `while True` loop is `break`…

Comment: Also, python gives importance to indentation. Your ```else:``` is outside the while loop

Comment: @Sujay No, `while..else` is actually a thing.

Comment: The increment of `idx` in code 1 should be done outside the `if` block

Comment: If you want something to run after your while loop ends (even if it hit a break),  don't put it in an else block. Just put it after your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` is going to get executed when the while condition becomes false. In the case of `break` you are just leaving the loop and True can never become False hence the `else` is not getting executed.

You can easily fix this with a condition variable instead of brake:

```
test_list = [1, 2, 3, 5]
condition = True
idx = 0

while condition:
    if test_list[idx] == 3:
        print("found it")
        condition = False
        idx += 1

else:
    print("not found it")
```